# MVC site using WebAPI - ignore API routes in MVC Route Config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

I'm using WebAPI in my MVC project and I'm facing an issue where the API routes are being handled by MVC routing. I can get around this by changing the order the routes are registered in e.g:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

    // Register API routes first 
    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);      
}
```

But I was wondering if it's possible to do this via the [IgnoreRoute()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505203(v=vs.118).aspx) method, I've tried:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("api/{controller}/{*folder}");
```

But I get a `404` back which seems to indicate that the request is still being handled by MVC routing and not WebAPI as before.

Here is my API route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{folder}",
            defaults: new { folder = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Added MVC route:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Info", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Show your mvc route config. You probably have a route in there that is matching your api routes

Comment: I normally add my web api routes before mvc routes

Comment: @Nkosi Edited to add, however I already know this, I'm looking for a way of preventing it being matched by the `IgnoreRoutes()` method.

Comment: Shouldn't `routes.IgnoreRoute("api/{*any}");` be enough?

Comment: Ok. my apologies. I misunderstood your issue

Comment: @jgauffin i'll give this a try

Comment: @jgauffin I still get a 404 unfortunately.

Comment: I believe both mvc and web api routes end up in same routing table. if you ignore `api/{*any}` you are essentially undoing your api route config

Comment: Introduce a custom constraint which says that the Controller name cannot be `api`. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs

Comment: @jgauffin Thanks - this appears to be the solution

Comment: @DGibbs: added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce a custom constraint which says that the Controller name cannot be `api`.

Here is an example based on the [MVC documentation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs)

```
public class NoApiControllerConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match
        (
            HttpContextBase httpContext, 
            Route route, 
            string parameterName, 
            RouteValueDictionary values, 
            RouteDirection routeDirection
        )
    {
        return values["controller"] != "api";
    }
}

routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}",
        new {controller="Home"},
        new {isNotForApi=new NoApiControllerConstraint()}
);
```